# Adding multiple values in ajax

Tags: ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(value){ 
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
var url="./checkajax";
url=url+"?adminid="+value;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
xmlHttp.send(null)
}

function stateChanged(){ 
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){ 
var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText; 
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML= showdata;
} }
function GetXmlHttpObject(){
var xmlHttp=null;
try{
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
catch (e) {
try {
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
catch (e){
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}}
return xmlHttp;}

</script>
```

I have included adminid inside the url, I also want to include "email" beside adminid. How to add it inside? It is something like adding multiple values inside the url.

Answer (score 0):

Use "?adminid="+value+"&email="+email;